# Looking for assistance with Graphic Card Dtriver. Help

Tags: drivers

I am using a Galaxy Nvidia GeForce GT610 Graphics Card on my console while running the Ubuntu 14.04LTS OS. I am confused. I need to figure out which of the drivers would be the best that apear to use in the list of Drivers available....?? Someone. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

One of them will say "Recommended" to the right, and when you highlight it the description area will say "tested" and have a little red ribbon next to it.  Those are generally the ones I pick.